# Cheerio grab FAQ Q/A from a HTML page that has the answer hidden behind a AccordionSummaryToggle

Tags: jquery, json, cheerio

**Scraping FAQ Page Answers**

I am trying to scrape FAQ pages and separate each of the questions and answers on a page into a different object.

I was able to extract the questions with this:

```
$(".accordion-group").map((i, e) => ({
   title: $("head > title").text(),
   question: $(".faqfield-question", e).text(),
/ FAQ Answer can't render without pressing + button
   answer: "FAQ Answer here:" + $(".faqfield-answer",e).text(),
}));
```

However I couldn't access the Answer as the tag `$(".faqfield-answer")` is hidden behind an accordion "+" toggle

As a workaround...

I was able to find all of the `.faqfield-answers` in this block at the bottom of the page with this line:

```
console.log($('script[id="__NEXT_DATA__"]').get(0).children[0].data);
```

However I was not sure how to extract the `.faqfield-answer` given this JSON block. Where all the answers, rather than one at a time, are in the "block_content"

```js
{
  "props": {
    "initialProps": {
      "pageProps": {
        "errorCode": 0,
        "contentData": {
          "field_fp_page_components": {
            "paragraph": [{
              "field_fp_hd_onedigital_vcaptn": [],
              "field_fp_hd_onedigital_videothum": []
            }, {
              "field_common_1d_block": {
                "block_content": [
                  "{\"name\":\"FAQBlock\",... \"answer\":{\"processed\":\"\u003cdiv class=\\\"faqfield-answer\\\"\u003e\u003cp\u003eYes, as part of our commitment to support ..., \"answer\":{\"processed\":\"\u003cdiv class=\\\"faqfield-answer\\\"\u003e\u003cp\u003eYes.
```

I'm pretty new with Cheerio, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$('script[id="**NEXT_DATA**"]').get(0).children[0].data is in itself a JSON, so...

```
const block_content = JSON.parse(
        $('script[id="__NEXT_DATA__"]').get(0).children[0].data
      ).props.initialProps.pageProps.contentData.field_fp_page_components
        .paragraph[1].field_common_1d_block.block_content;
```

Gives you another JSON so to get to the faqfield-answer

```
JSON.parse(block_content).faq_details.map((faq) => ({answer: $("div", faq.answer.processed).text()))
```

Gives you each of the answers!

Key was using JSON.parse twice